# In C++, when inheriting a class and overriding a function. I get an unexpected result when calling that overrided function from an array

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a class named House that extends from a class named City.

```
class City
{
public:
    string get(){
        return "San Francisco"
    }
};

class House : public City
{
public:
    string get(){
        return "My House"
    }
};

int main()
{
    City world[2];
    House h;
    world[0] = h;
    cout << world[0].get() << endl;
}
```

The result I want back is "My House", but instead I get "San Francisco". Why is this and how do I fix it? I thought that if you named a function the same as a function existing in the inherited class, then that function would always be called.

Answer (score 1):

for what you looking for you should use `virtual` keyword,
like this:

```
class City
{
public:
    virtual ~City() {}//you need virtual destructor  
    virtual string get(){
        return "San Francisco"
    }
};
```

also you need to use pointers instead of value to achieve what you want:

```
City *world[2];
world[0] = new House;
cout << world[0]->get() << endl; 
delete world[0];
```

Comment: Correct answer, but I think OP wanted an explanation of "why" as well.  It might be helpful if you added this.

Answer (score 1):

Which function will be called is determined at compile time. For your case, `City::get()` will always be called because the type of array's element is `City`.

Note that `world[0] = h;` will cause [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing), `House` will be copied(sliced) as `City`.

If you want dynamic polymorphism, you need to call the member funtion via pointer or reference. And you need to make the member function `virtual`. Such as

```
class City
{
public:
    virtual string get() {
        return "San Francisco";
    }
    virtual ~City() {}
};

class House : public City
{
public:
    virtual string get() override {
        return "My House";
    }
};

int main()
{
    City* world[2];
    House h;
    world[0] = &h;
    cout << world[0]->get() << endl;
}
```